# How to make a Latex Table with text in one column and multiline equations in another?

Tags: tables, equations, tabularray

I'm making tables describing my models and I don't know how to put multiline equations inside a table. I tried using multirow, but the results are super weird, and I tried using align* inside a cell, but I got an error.

The closest thing I got to work is using a tabular inside a cell, but the layout is a bit weird: the text cells have a weird padding on top, while the equations cells have no padding.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow,rotating,lscape,amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx,ragged2e}
\begin{document}
    \begin{landscape}
    \begin{table}
    \centering
        \label{submodels-for-derived-variables}
        \begin{tabular}{|p{0.3\textwidth}|p{0.3\textwidth}|p{0.4\textwidth}|}
            \textbf{Modelled variable}
            & \textbf{Parameters}
            & \textbf{Formula}\\ 
            \hline
            Fire spread probability from cell \textit{a} to cell \textit{b}, \textit{plain} topography
            & Grass flammability parameter (\textit{f}), grass cell \textit{b} biomass (\textit{Bb})
            & $F_{\text{ab}} = \text{fB}_{b}$ \\ 
            \hline
            Fire spread probability from cell \textit{a} to cell \textit{b}, non-plain topography
            & Grass flammability parameter (f), grass biomass (Bb), slope between \textit{a} and \textit{b} (\textit{sab})
            & \begin{tabular}{lll}
                        $F_t =fB_b,$            & $s  >= 0.4,$ \\
                        $F_t =( s+0.6 )fB_b,$   &$s \in (-0.4,0.4)$\\
                        $F_t =0.2fB_b,$         &$s <= -0.4   $ \\
            \end{tabular}\\

            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image: table image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the cool new `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow,rotating,lscape,amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx,ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
    \begin{landscape}
    \begin{table}
    \centering
        \begin{tblr}{vlines,hlines,colspec={X[l,valign=m]X[l,valign=m]Q[l,valign=m]}}
            \textbf{Modelled variable}
            & \textbf{Parameters}
            & \textbf{Formula}  \\ 
            Fire spread probability from cell \textit{a} to cell \textit{b}, \textit{plain} topography
            & Grass flammability parameter (\textit{f}), grass cell \textit{b} biomass (\textit{Bb})
            &  $F_{\text{ab}} = \text{fB}_{b}$ \\ 
            Fire spread probability from cell \textit{a} to cell \textit{b}, non-plain topography
            & Grass flammability parameter (f), grass biomass (Bb), slope between \textit{a} and \textit{b} (\textit{sab})
            & \begin{tblr}{@{}ll@{}}  
              $F_t =fB_b,$           &  $s  >= 0.4,$ \\
              $F_t =( s+0.6 )fB_b,$ &  $s \in (-0.4,0.4)$\\
              $F_t =0.2fB_b,$       &  $s <= -0.4   $ \\
            \end{tblr}\\
        \end{tblr}
    \end{table}
    \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can also omit the `valign` and just write e.g. `X[l,m]`. For the underlined keys in the tabularray [documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) one can usually just use the value without the key.

Comment: is it tabularry or tabularray?

Comment: how do I install this package? it doesn't seem to be inscluded in my miktex distribution

Answer (score 2):

Your alignment can be fixed by passing an optional argument to `tabular`. Here's a remake of your table using [`booktabs`](//ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) and [`tabularx`](//ctan.org/pkg/tabularx):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs,amsmath,tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ p{0.3\linewidth} p{0.3\linewidth} X }
    \toprule
    \textbf{Modelled variable} & 
      \textbf{Parameters} &
      \textbf{Formula} \\ 
    \midrule
    Fire spread probability from cell \textit{a} to cell \textit{b}, \textit{plain} topography & 
      Grass flammability parameter (\textit{f}), grass cell \textit{b} biomass (\textit{Bb}) & 
      $F_{\text{ab}} = \text{fB}_{b}$ \\ 
    \addlinespace
    Fire spread probability from cell \textit{a} to cell \textit{b}, non-plain topography & 
      Grass flammability parameter (f), grass biomass (Bb), slope between \textit{a} and \textit{b} (\textit{sab}) &
      \begin{tabular}[t]{ @{} l l @{} }
        $F_t = fB_b$,            & $s \geq 0.4$,        \\
        $F_t = (s + 0.6) fB_b$,  & $s \in (-0.4, 0.4)$, \\
        $F_t = 0.2 fB_b$,        & $s \leq -0.4$.
      \end{tabular} \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Note the use of `\begin{tabular}[t]` to set the anchor point for the `tabular` to the `[t]`op.

Your original table is too wide for the page; the column widths add up to `\textwidth`, but there is horizontal padding around each column, as well as the vertical rule widths. In such cases where you want a full-width table, but you're not sure about the column width calculations, consider using `tabularx` (with at least one `X`-column).

Answer (score 2):

With use of `amsmath` and `tabularray` (version 2021Q) package.

**Edit:**
Writing of variables seems to be inconsistent. I try to write all of them in math mode. If this is not what you after, revert these changes to your notation (with `\textit` ...)

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
    \begin{table}
        \begin{tblr}{vlines,hlines,
                     colspec={X[l,m] X[l,m] X[l,m,$]},
                     row{1} = {font=\bfseries, mode=text, c}
                     }
Modelled variable 
    &   Parameters 
        &   Formula                         \\
Fire spread probability from cell $a$ to cell $b$, plain topography
    & Grass flammability parameter $(f)$, grass cell $b$ biomass $(B_b)$
        &   F_{\text{ab}} = fB_{b}   \\
Fire spread probability from cell $a$ to cell $b$, non-plain topography
    &   Grass flammability parameter $(f)$, grass biomass $(B_{b})$, slope between $a$ and $b$ $(\mathit{sab})$
        &   F_t = \begin{cases}
                f B_b,          &   s \geq 0.4,           \\
                (s + 0.6)fB_b,  &   s \in (-0.4,0.4)    \\
                0.2fB_b,        &   s \leq -0.4           \\
            \end{cases}                     \\
        \end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank-you for fixing all the inconsistencies in my code! they were created by an amateur pandoc translation... I also didn't know about cases, so this fixes all my problems! why did you change lscape to pdflscape tho?

Comment: @MOzSalles, `pdflscape` and `lscape` difer how the landscape is presented on the scree, `pdflscape` turn page so, that we can easy read, however meanwhile `lscape` not. In the printed document both produced the same (right) result.